# FIN_WAIT Issue With Java Monitoring Application

Tags: java, tcp

Having issues with FIN_WAIT1 on my RHEL 5.4 running Introscope. What I have observed so far is whenever the target JVM which we are monitoring using Introscope is hung the agent running on that host stop sending data and after some time the socket on the server (Introscope Server) goes in FIN_WAIT1 state and it remains there for a long time it gets cleaned up if we restart the target JVM.

I would like to know if this is happening because of a bug in Introscope or is it something to do with TCP layer.

Answer (score 0):

FIN_WAIT1 is at the TCP layer - it means your computer's tcp stack is waiting for one of the connection-close messages from the other side's TCP stack.  It usually doesn't really cause much harm, other than taking some tiny amount of kernel state until it times out.  However sometimes it can prevent you from restarting a server on the same port, in which case you can set the SO_REUSESOCKET and/or SO_REUSEPORT options on the socket before opening it the first time.  (This does have some security implications if you're sharing the machine.)